# Como fazer um "select distinct" em um modelo no Laravel?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Estou puxando os dados de uma tabela para um `select`, porém tenho campos onde a informação é igual, por exemplo:

**Controller:**

```
$amostragens = Amostragem::all();
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($amostragens as $amostragem)
     <option value="{{ $amostragem->id }}">{{ $amostragem->analito }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Tabela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então acaba ficando coisa repetida dentro do `select` quando eu vou exibir o "analito".

Preciso mostrar por exemplo apenas 1 "Acetato de etila", e em outro select ou ja tenho algo preparado para exibir todas as opções de "coletor" que tem o analito selecionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `GroupBy()`

```
$amostragens = Amostragem::select('id', 'analito')->groupBy('analito')->get();
```

Usando `Distinct()`

Fluente

```
DB::table('amostragem')->distinct()->get(['analito']);
```

Eloquente

```
Amostragem::distinct()->get(['analito']);
```

Comment: Funcionou @Zoom, obrigado!